# Images upload error

Tags: php, html

I'm having the following problem. I use input form with four validated text input fields (not allowed to be empty), and three file input fields below on the same form. When I try to upload images which are smaller in size, everything works ok. But when I choose a larger pictures, like 1MB or so, I get the validation error on text input fields even though I filled them.

```
$ime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ime']);
$mesto = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mesto']);
$telefon = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefon']);
$emajl = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emajl']);
$opis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opis']);

if ((empty($ime)) || (empty($mesto)) || (empty($telefon)) || (empty($emajl))){echo "Moraju biti uneti podaci u obavezna polja"; exit;}
//unos slike1
if ((($_FILES["slika1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["slika1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["slika1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["slika1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["slika1"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["slika1"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["slika1"]["size"] < 2097152))
{
if ($_FILES["slika1"]["error"] > 0)
 {
 echo "Greška: " . $_FILES["slika1"]["error"] . "<br>";
 }
else
 {
$razdvajanje = explode('.',$_FILES['slika1']['name']);
 $ekstenzija = $razdvajanje[1];
$novoime = mysql_real_escape_string($razdvajanje[0]).'_'.time();     
 $putanja = 'uploads/' . $novoime . "." . $ekstenzija;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['slika1']['tmp_name'], $putanja);
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Slika mora biti manja od 2MB i u adekvatnom formatu";
```

The error I get is "Moraju biti uneti podaci u obavezna polja" even the field is not empty. When I try to upload just one larger image, it also works. It's only not working when I try to upload three 1MB images at the same time.

Just to be clear. Script is working on localhost (XAMPP). I am having issues when uploading to my web hosting server. Also, the script is working when I upload 3 image files that are around 300kb, but when I try to upload 3 files that are around 1MB in size, the process fail at around 60%. I don't think that problem is in size, but in upload time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to increase the size allowed in php.ini
or do something like this

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('max_file_uploads', '20');
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. maybe you need to set the max file uploads as well. make sure this is run before anything else

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the filesize and override the default size set by PHP:

Something like this:

```
$size1=$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;
$max_allowed_file_size = 50000;

if($size1 >= 0)
{
    if($size1> $max_allowed_file_size )
    {
    $err[]= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
    }
}
```

Just modify your script with the filesize and you should be fine.

Comment: This is just an example on how to use the file size to ensure you are able to submit larges files.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- Search your php.ini. (mine is under /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)
- Edit "post_max_size" to 5M
- Edit "upload_max_filesize" to 5M
- Edit "max_file_uploads" to 20 (<- this value determines how many files can be uploaded using a single request.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using hosting service, can't access Apache.

Comment: I think that problem might be in web server settings, because the code works on localhost. Probably the time for upload is not enough, and server closes the connection.

Comment: This could be! If you had access to apache, increasing 'max_execution_time = 30' from default 30s to 120s could help.
Maybe you can open a ticket at your hoster to request those changes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem by limiting image size to 500kb. It works now. I mean, I did not solve the problem, I avoided it.